# What is the difference between "class" and "class_" in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

```
tags = soup.find_all(class='sister')
for tag in tags:
    print(tag)
```

In python with bs4, when I write this code up above then, I find my output

> Error Invalid Syntax "class"

If I use underscore (_) with class "class_", then it works.

Comment: You really can't think of a special meaning that the word `class` has in Python? And you're trying to use third-party libraries to connect to the Internet and analyze data? Please make sure you understand the fundamentals of the language first.

Comment: Alternately, what happens if you try putting `python syntax class` into a search engine?

Answer (score 4):

- **`class` (no underscore)** is one of the [reserved keywords](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords) in Python:

  > The following identifiers are used as reserved words, or ***keywords*** of the language, and cannot be used as ordinary identifiers:
  >
  > ```
  > False      await      else       import     pass
  > None       break      except     in         raise
  > True       class      finally    is         return
  > and        continue   for        lambda     try
  > as         def        from       nonlocal   while
  > assert     del        global     not        with
  > async      elif       if         or         yield
  > ```
- **`class_` (with underscore)** has no special meaning in general. `bs4` just wanted a CSS "class" param, but `class` is reserved [so they chose `class_` with an underscore](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class):

  > Using `class` as a keyword argument will give you a syntax error. As of Beautiful Soup 4.1.2, you can search by CSS class using the keyword argument `class_`:
  >
  > ```
  > soup.find_all("a", class_="sister")
  > ```